# Lightning Component created for quick action. Will that need users to have lightning enabled to see it in salesforce1?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have created a lightning component for quick action on record detail page. Will that need every user to have lightning enabled to see that component in Salesforce1.

Comment: did you try to access it from salesforce mobile app?

Comment: Asking for possibility. I'm yet to create component.

Comment: Lightning Quick actions are available in the mobile app. You can even use mobile cards.

Comment: Will that need every user to have lightning enabled to see that component in Salesforce1?

Comment: It will be visible by default